# Left-aligning definitions by symbols

Tags: formatting, lists

I need to have the output have the definitions left aligned by the tab of 1.5 cm (so not under the symbols). When I used `\hangindent` or `flushleft`, it becomes left aligned, but loses the tab. I am just starting out with LaTeX. I even tried using `\par`, but couldn't figure it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}  
  \item[] $\sigma_i$    \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Ionic conductivity [$\frac{mho}{m}$] for water, [15, p. 26].
  \item[] $\phi$    \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Phase advance associated with complex earth reflection coefficient used in (155).
  \item[] $\phi_{g,c}$  \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Phase shift [rad] of effective reflection coefficient for earth or counterpoise reflection, used in (156).
  \item[] $\phi_{kg,c}$ \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Knife-edge diffraction phase shift [rad] for earth or counterpoise reflection, from (138).
  \item[] $\phi_{Tg,c}$ \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm}Total phase shift [rad] of effective reflection coefficient for earth or counterpoise reflection, from (157).
  \item[] $\psi$ \linebreak \tabto{1.5cm} Grazing angle shown in Figures 8 and 9.
  \item[] $|_c$ \linebreak  \tabto{1.5cm} Expression evaluated for specific conditions such as climate or time block in (267).
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Answer (score 1):

The following example sets the left margin of the environment `itemize` locally to `1.5cm`. The symbol are put into the optional argument of `\item`, but left-aligned.

`\samepage` is used to prevent that there are page breaks inside the lines for a symbol and its description. Page breaks are allowed before a symbol.
This way, the symbol list can be several pages long and page breaks are between symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{1.5cm}
  \def\Item[#1]{%
    \par\nopagebreak[2]% 0 to 3
    \item[\hbox to \labelwidth{#1\hss}]\mbox{}\\%
  }
  \begin{itemize}
    \samepage
    \Item[$\sigma_i$]
      Ionic conductivity [$\frac{mho}{m}$] for water, [15, p. 26].
    \Item[$\phi$]
      Phase advance associated with complex earth reflection coefficient
      used in (155).
    \Item[$\phi_{g,c}$]
      Phase shift [rad] of effective reflection coefficient for earth or
      counterpoise reflection, used in (156).
    \Item[$\phi_{kg,c}$]
      Knife-edge diffraction phase shift [rad] for earth or counterpoise
      reflection, from (138).
    \Item[$\phi_{Tg,c}$]
      Total phase shift [rad] of effective reflection coefficient for earth
      or counterpoise reflection, from (157).
    \Item[$\psi$]
      Grazing angle shown in Figures 8 and 9.
    \Item[$|_c$]
      Expression evaluated for specific conditions such as climate or time
      block in (267).
  \end{itemize}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Alternatively, environment `description` can be used. But then, the font in the label is by default bold. This can be overwritten by adding `\mdseries`.
- The dollars for inline math could be added to the macro `\Item`. However, this makes it harder (practically impossible) for TeX editors to recognize math.

BTW, instead of hard-coded numbers for figure references and the citations, the LaTeX commands such as `\label`, `\ref`, and `\cite` should be used. Then, if the text changes, the numbers are updated automatically.

Comment: Maybe ``\\*`` would avoid the need for `\samepage`.

Comment: @egreg A description can have more than one line with possible page breaks between lines.

Comment: `\linepenalty=10000`?

Comment: @egreg `\samepage` is shorter and covers more cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using a `tabularx` environment rather than an `itemize` environment.

[image]

Observe the use of `\si` (a macro provided by the `siunitx` package) to format scientific units.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' env. and '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{siunitx}   % for '\si' macro
\begin{document}
\noindent
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}} % X column for descriptive material
$\sigma_i$   
   & Ionic conductivity [\si{mho\per\meter}] for water [15, p.~26].\\
$\phi$
   & Phase advance associated with complex earth reflection 
     coefficient used in (155).\\
$\phi_{\si{\gram},c}$
   & Phase shift [\si{\radian}] of effective reflection coefficient 
     for earth or counterpoise reflection, used in (156).\\
$\phi_{\si{\kilo\gram},c}$
   & Knife-edge diffraction phase shift [\si{\radian}] for earth or 
     counterpoise reflection, from (138).\\
$\phi_{\si{\tera\gram},c}$
   & Total phase shift [\si{\radian}] of effective reflection 
     coefficient for earth or counterpoise reflection, from (157).\\
$\psi$       
   & Grazing angle shown in Figures 8 and 9.\\
$|_c$        
   &  Expression evaluated for specific conditions such as climate 
      or time block in (267).\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the left-hand column has to be exactly 1.5cm wide, I suggest you  replace `l` with `p{1.5cm}` in the code:

```
\noindent
\begingroup
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm}X} % 1st col. exactly 1.5cm wide
$\sigma_i$   
   & Ionic conductivity [\si{mho\per\meter}] for water [15, p.~26].\\
... % remainder of tabular material
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
```